# How do I write a Python if statement Function to identify if 3 dimensions make up a triangle?

Tags: python

I need to write a function with if statements to find if a triangle with 3 given sides is a triangle or not.

```
 def makes_triangle(a, b, c):
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the if statements

Comment: basically like if its a triangle, it returns "it is a triangle"

Comment: First you need to know which mathematical condition(s) the dimensions must fulfill to describe a triangle. Do you know that?

Answer (score 6):

You need to use the [triangle inequality theorem](https://www.wikihow.com/Determine-if-Three-Side-Lengths-Are-a-Triangle#:%7E:text=All%20you%20have%20to%20do,you%20will%20have%20a%20triangle.):

```
def makes_triangle(a, b, c):
    return (a+b>c) and (a+c>b) and (b+c>a)
```